# How can I decrease the width of crystal report toolbar?

Tags: c#, browser, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports version 10.5.3700.0 and .NET framework 3.5

I want to adjust the tool bar which are coming when I include the crystal report in a web form. It looks proper in Mozilla browsers but in Internet Explorer 8 it doesn't look so good. Its width is too high.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should use: `Toolbarstyle-width = "780 px"`

Comment: there is no property like Toolbarstyle-width... Its not working for me